# How to use a MongoDB collection in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have one server file that is `server.js`.

I have a MongoDB connection inside this file like this:

```
var Db=require('mongodb').Db;
var BSON=require('mongodb').BSONPure;
var Server=require('mongodb').Server;

client=new Db('database' , new Server('127.0.0.1',27017),{safe:false});

client.open(function(err,pClient)
{
    client.collection('userdetails',function(err,collection)
    {
        Ucollection=collection;
    });
});
```

I have another file named `server2.js`. In this file I have to check if a username exists or not from `Ucollection` (this is collection name).

How can I give the MongoDB connection to `server2.js`? How can I use this collection in `server2.js`?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

**in server.js:**

```
var Db=require('mongodb').Db;
var BSON=require('mongodb').BSONPure;
var Server=require('mongodb').Server;

global.mongoHelper = {};
global.mongoHelper.db = Db;
global.mongoHelper.bson = BSON;
global.mongoHelper.server = Server;


client=new Db('database' , new Server('127.0.0.1',27017),{safe:false});

client.open(function(err,pClient)
{
    client.collection('userdetails',function(err,collection)
    {
        Ucollection=collection;
    });
});
```

**in server2.js**

```
client=new global.mongoHelper.db('database' , new global.mongoHelper.server('127.0.0.1',27017),{safe:false});

client.open(function(err,pClient)
{
    client.collection('userdetails',function(err,collection)
    {
        Ucollection=collection;
    });
});
```

Comment: Like that, I think you could even reuse the collection!

Comment: where would i give accept.i don't know how to give.let me know that. again i have one doubt can i use that coding into more files or not?

Comment: Yes, you can use the same method to in any other server side js file.
regarding how to accept an answer, check this out: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/149316

Comment: in one server file its working but in another file i have tried and got this error  TypeError: Cannot read property 'db' of undefined
that's y i asked like that.

Comment: I think the file which gives you error gets executed before `server.js` gets executed. Change the order of your execution. `server.js` should always be executed first. Otherwise see khurrum qureshi's answer{http://stackoverflow.com/a/15516748/405398} it's neat.

Answer (score 1):

I think much cleaner way of doing this is to seprate your database configration into seprate file. Like this

**in database-config.js**

```
var Db=require('mongodb').Db;
var BSON=require('mongodb').BSONPure;
var Server=require('mongodb').Server;

client=new Db('database' , new Server('127.0.0.1',27017),{safe:false});

module.exports.connectDatabase = function(callback){
   client.open(function(err,pClient)
   {
       if(err){
         console.log(err);
         process.exit(1);
       }

       module.exports.userCollection = pClient.collection('userdetails');
       callback();
   });
}
```

**in server.js**

```
var  database = require('./database-config')
database.connectDatabase(function() {
   //here you can reuse collection like this
   database.userCollection

}
```

**in server2.js**

```
var  database = require('./database-config')
//here you can reuse collection like this
   database.userCollection
```

I am assuming that server.js is your main file which actually intiate server so when you run your application it connects to database and load required collections which you can use anywhere in your application like I did this is considered as best practice to re-use collections. Let me know if there is any confusion

Answer (score 0):

Well you are a bit mistaken about the whole concept of modularizing the code. For your task, you should not make a second server.js. You can make another module say, verifyUser and require it in your server.js file. You may require it (may be) after your mongodb connection.

Comment: i can't understand.plz let me know that how to use this collection name into another file.

Answer (score 0):

server.js

```
var Db=require('mongodb').Db;
var BSON=require('mongodb').BSONPure;
var Server=require('mongodb').Server;

client=new Db('database' , new Server('127.0.0.1',27017),{safe:false});

client.open(function(err,pClient)
{

     exports.Ucollection=pClient;
  });
});
```

server2.js

```
  var mongodb = require('mongodb');
  var mainApp=require('./server');
  var collectionObj=mainApp.Ucollection;
  var collection = new mongodb.Collection(collectionObj, 'userdetails');
```

Using this collection.you can query like below

```
  collection.insert(userInfo,{safe:true},function(err, objects) {
    if(!err){
       console.log('Data inserted successfully.');
     }

  });
```